# My code for solving n queens problem Compile Failed

Tags: programming, performance-tuning, compile

I want to make my code for solving [n-queens problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) faster,
but it seems that `MapIndexed` can't be compiled. Mathematica return

> CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression If[Abs[1-Compile`GetElement[{2},1]]==1,Throw[False]] should be a machine-size real number. >>

```
Clear["`*"];
safe[col_, queens_] := 
  FreeQ[queens, col] && 
   Catch[MapIndexed[
     If[Abs[col - #] == Length@queens - First@#2 + 1, Throw@False] &, 
     queens];
    True];

safeCompiled = 
  Compile[{{col, _Integer}, {queens, _Integer, 1}}, 
   FreeQ[queens, col] && 
    Catch[MapIndexed[
      If[Abs[col - #] == Length@queens - First@#2 + 1, Throw@False] &,
       queens];
     True]
   ];

8 /. size_ :>
    Nest[Table[sol~Append~i, 
      {i, size}, {sol, Select[#, safeCompiled[i, #] &]}]~Flatten~1 &,
     {{}}, size] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

**Updated**

A bit faster version:

```
safe = Compile[{{col, _Integer}, {queens, _Integer, 1}}, 
   If[MemberQ[queens, col], Return@0];
   Catch[Do[If[Abs[col - queens[[i]] ] == Length@queens - i + 1, Throw@0],
      {i, Length@queens}]; 1],
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable];

size = 11;
iter = Table[Append[sol, i], {i, size}, {sol, Pick[#, safe[i, #], 1]}]~ Flatten~1 &;
Nest[iter, List /@ Range@size, size - 1] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.083062, 2680}

Comment: Just in case http://www.lauschkeconsulting.net/nqueens.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the return value of

```
If[Abs[col - #] == Length@queens - First@#2 + 1, Throw@False] &
```

which needs to be of a type handled by [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html).  The `If` statement returns `Null` when the test is not `True`, and `Compile` does not support `Null`.

One fix is to make the value of the function be `0` (or whatever, since this value is not used).

```
safeCompiled = 
 Compile[{{col, _Integer}, {queens, _Integer, 1}}, 
  FreeQ[queens, col] && 
   Catch[MapIndexed[(If[Abs[col - #] == Length@queens - First@#2 + 1, 
        Throw@False]; 0) &, queens];
    True]]
```

A slightly more efficient approach is to use `Do`, since the list created by `MapThread` is immaterial.

```
safeCompiled = 
 Compile[{{col, _Integer}, {queens, _Integer, 1}}, 
  FreeQ[queens, col] && 
   Catch[Do[
     If[Abs[col - queens[[i]]] == Length@queens - i + 1, Throw@False],
     {i, Length @ queens}];
    True]]

8 /. size_ :> 
    Nest[Table[sol ~Append~ i,
      {i, size}, {sol, Select[#, safeCompiled[i, #] &]}] ~Flatten~ 1 &,
      {{}}, size] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.023975, 92} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

MapIndexed is not a compilable function until Mathematica 9.
See more information in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/2266).

Comment: Try ``Compile`CompilerFunctions[]~MemberQ~MapIndexed``.